# The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle()

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi guys I'm having a little problem here, when i call the `getActionBar()` I get the error:

> The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type new
>   ActionBarDrawerToggle()

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)
    {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

        }
    };
```

The code for the ActionBarDrawerToggle is this one:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}
```

I'm using the tuturial from [tuturial link](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android) to this.

Comment: Are you using the support library with the v4 FragmentActivity?

Comment: Yep I have that Library on the project

Comment: does getSupportActionBar() work instead? You may have to be using an ActionBarActivity as well if you intend to support Android < 4.0

Comment: Nop doesn't work too The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined

Comment: Could you post the code of your activity which the ActionBarDrawerToggle is in?

Comment: I wish I could but don't have authorization to past the all code in here, and its a little big by now :/

Comment: Are you using ActionBarCompact ? On which android version you are running the code?

Comment: Hey Adnan, I have changed the code, and I'm using the Drawer now, and is working like a charme :)

Comment: Sry but why change the title like that? Don't change the constructor of ActionBarDrawerToggle the text automatically? Therefore you have R.string.drawer_open and R.string.drawer_close...